# ¿Cómo puedo guardar un archivo en la SD?

Tags: java, android

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo guardar un archivo en la SD (memoria externa)?

Estoy intentando mediante el uso de:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

pero siempre lo guarda en la memoria interna.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hola @MauricioAriasOlave, considero que de inicio ayudemos a los usuarios que recién se integran a [es.so] a explicar el por qué su pregunta puede ser cerrada, acto seguido como bien lo mencionas indicarle las páginas para que se documente al respecto de cómo generar una buena pregunta. En mi opinión la pregunta no es mala, solo es muy directa, lo cual es completamente diferente.

Comment: El usuario ha explicado con claridad su problema. Y ha puesto el código que ha intentado. Solo falta responderle cómo se guarda un archivo en la SD. Gracias por tu interesante y correcta pregunta, Edgar. Si añades [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) entonces tu pregunta pasará de buena a excelente y además recibirás mejor ayuda.

Comment: hola lograste resolver tu problema de escribir el archivo en la micro sd? si fue asi como lo lograste... veo que la gente se confunde cuando dicen memoria externa y piensan que es la micro sd. La memoria interna del sistema es una y la memoria externa es una sd integrada dentro del mismo telefono que funge como memoria externa... extra a esto tenemos el almacenamiento en Micro sd, QUE NO ES MEMORIA EXTERNA, pq como bien dices el archivo no se genera en la misma micro sd, si no que aparece creado en la memoria del telefono, pero en la mal llamada memoria externa.
1.-memoria Interna 2.- memoria

Answer (score 1):

Agrega tu código pero lo que comentas no es posible:

> Uso  Environment.[getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) pero siempre lo guarda en >la memoria interna

**Definitivamente mediante [getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) se obtiene la ruta del almacenamiento externo**, este debe ser usado como ruta para guardar tu archivo.

Este es un método de ejemplo para escribir un archivo:

```
private void writeToExternalStorage(){

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  "/midirectorio");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "miArchivo.txt");
    try {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
        pw.println("Hola Stackoverflow.");
        pw.println("......");
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        f.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error " + e.getMessage());
    }   

}
```

el método obtiene una ruta por medio de [getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()), crea un directorio y escribe un archivo dentro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si pero no lo esta guardando en la sd la esta guardando en la memoria interna

Comment: Como sabes que lo guarda en la memoria interna, si obtienes el path mediante getExternalStorageDirectory() no es posible que tome un path de la interna, como determinas que se guarda en la interna?

Comment: pues por que no esta creando el directoria en la sd lo esta creando en la memoria interna

Comment: Que path obtienes con ;: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: el de la ruta de la sd  lo puse en un log pero aun a si no logro poder guardar en la sd sera por la version de android que es superior a la 4.4 o el dispositivo ?

Comment: Usa el método propuesto y revisa si se creo un archivo en la ruta que comento, si usas como path Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , no es posible que tome un path de almacenamiento interno.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/carpeta1/carpeta2");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "filename");

FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
```