# ¿Cómo vertificar si ya existe una carpeta en Android?

Tags: java, android

Buenas tardes/días/noches.

Estoy haciendo una app para tomar unas fotos y necesito guardarlas en una carpeta, la cosa es que cada que abro la app se me crea la carpeta, la idea es que si ya esta creada no se sobre-escriba.

Lo que estoy haciendo es que tengo una imagen en un ImageView y la voy a guardar, por lo cual, cree una clase que se llama save y programe el boton Guardar. LA IDEA ES QUE YO LEPONGA EL NOMBRE A LA IMAGEN, POR LO CUAL, CREE UN EDIT TEXT PARA CAPTURARLO.

El boton guardar esta asi:

```
Save savefile= new Save();
String nombrecito=txtNombre.getText().toString();
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmp2= imageView.getDrawingCache();
savefile.SaveImage(MainActivity.this,bmp2,nombrecito);
```

y la clase la tengo programa asi:

```
public class Save {
    private Context TheThis;
    private String NameImagen;
    private String carpeta="DECOM";

    public void SaveImage(Context context, Bitmap ImageToSave, String nombre)
    {
        TheThis =context;
        String file_path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+carpeta;
        File dir = new File(file_path);
        if(!dir.exists())
        {
            Toast.makeText(TheThis,"HASTA ACA",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(dir,nombre+".jpg");
        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

        }catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            UnableToSave();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            UnableToSave();
        }

    }

    private void MakeSureFileWasCreatedThenMakeAvabile(File file){
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(TheThis,
                new String[] {file.toString()}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri){
                        Log.e("ExternalStorage","Scanned"+path+":");
                        Log.e("ExternalStorage","->uri="+uri);
                    }
                });
    }


  private void UnableToSave(){
      Toast.makeText(TheThis, "NO GUARDADA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  private void AbleToSave(){
        Toast.makeText(TheThis,"GUARDADA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Añade el código el cual has desarrollado, para poder ayudarte, saludos.

Comment: Te sugiero agregues tu código.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
                         File.separator + "MiCarpeta");
boolean success = true;
//  Si no existe, la creas.
if (!folder.exists()) {
    success = folder.mkdirs();
} else {
   //  En caso de existir.
}

if (success) {
    //  Si no hubo problema al crearla.
} else {
    // Algo en caso de tener problemas.
}
```

Con ello puedes controlar que hacer en un especifico escenario. Saludos.

Comment: Si mi respuesta te ayudó, no olvides marcarla como tal. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En realidad en Android es similar a java mediante el método [**exists()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) de la clase File.

```
File carpeta = new File(ruta);

if (carpeta.exists()) {  //Comprueba si existe.
  //........
}else{ //No existe.
  carpeta.mkdirs();  //Crea directorio.
}
```

De la documentación

> [**exists()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) : Comprueba si existe el archivo o directorio
>   denotado por esta ruta de acceso abstracta.

---

Relacionado a tu pregunta puedes revisar:

Guardar datos en el almacenamiento interno:

[Guardar archivo en data/data/package/](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55911/guardar-archivo-en-data-data-package)

guardar datos en la SDCard:

[¿Cómo puedo guardar un archivo en la SD?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51602/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-guardar-un-archivo-en-la-sd)